# How to check if I can bind to IP address?

Tags: go

I have an IP address and want to check if I can send requests to the internet from it.
I want to check this both for IPv4 addresses and IPv6 addresses.

The check should work for any IP address (local, public, docker's, lo, etc.).

From another angle, I want to see if I can bind to the address. For example, I have IPs set on my machine to which I can't bind (Tested via `curl --interface`) and want to filter those from my available addresses.

Usage: user inputs an IP address to send (http get) requests from, and I want to check if the IP is valid/usable.

EDIT on trying to bind and seeing if I can:
I've tried this:

```
tcpAddr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", ipString)
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   10 * time.Second,
            LocalAddr: tcpAddr,
        }).DialContext,
    },
}

_, err = client.Get("http://www.google.com/")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Unusable")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Usable")
}
```

It shows all available addresses (even loopback) as usable (Even checked response bodies; All were valid). Many of those aren't bindable through `curl --interface`.

Comment: Try binding and see if you get an error back.

Comment: @Adrian Added an example of my attempt to do just that to the question. If I've done it wrong, please elaborate more on how you mean.

Comment: This seems like n overcomplicated way to test this; I would probably literally try to bind a listener to the address with https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listen

Comment: @Adrian Thanks! That's much better than mine :) It still accepts `lo` addresses which I can filter elsewhere. I can still bind to private IPs, but I can handle that elsewhere too. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding it and see if you get an error:

```
l,err := net.Listen("tcp", address)
if err != nil {
    // address is not bindable
} else {
    l.Close()
}
```